# How to get the width of terminal window in Ruby

Tags: ruby, unix, terminal

Have you ever noticed that if you run rake -T in rails the list of rake descriptions are truncated by the width of the terminal window. So there should be a way to get it in Ruby and Use it.

I'm printing some Ascii-art on the screen and I don't want it to be broken. therefore I need to find out the width of terminal at run time some how.

Any Idea how to do that?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I've found that on Ubuntu, none of the other methods specified here (`ENV['COLUMNS']`, `tput columns` or hirb) give the correct result if the terminal is resized while the Ruby application is running. This is not an issue for scripts, but it is an issue for interactive consoles, such as irb.

The [ruby-terminfo gem](https://github.com/genki/ruby-terminfo) is the best solution I've find so far to give the correct dimensions after a resize, but it requires that you install an additional gem, and is unix-specific.

The gem's usage is simple:

```
require 'terminfo'
p TermInfo.screen_size        # [lines, columns]
```

TermInfo internally uses TIOCGWINSZ ioctl for the screen size.

Alternatively, as mentioned by user83510, highline's system_extensions also works:

```
require 'highline'
HighLine::SystemExtensions.terminal_size # [columns, lines]
```

Interally, highline uses `stty size` on Unix, and other implementations for ncurses and Windows.

To listen for changes to the terminal size (instead of polling), we can trap the SIGWINCH signal:

```
require 'terminfo'
Signal.trap('SIGWINCH', proc { puts TermInfo.screen_size.inspect })
```

This is specifically useful for applications using Readline, such as irb:

```
Signal.trap('SIGWINCH', proc { Readline.set_screen_size(TermInfo.screen_size[0], TermInfo.screen_size[1]) })
```

Comment: Under the hood ruby-terminfo is doing a call to `ioctl` with `TIOCGWINSZ` and a struct of 4 unsigned shorts. These are the columns, rows, and x, y in pixels. Here is a gist of this directly https://gist.github.com/nixpulvis/6025433.

Comment: For anyone still getting to this page, another lighter gem that does that is https://github.com/rking/terminal-size

Comment: On my system it's `tput cols` and not `tput columns`.

Comment: I wrote a gem to do just that https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty-screen

Comment: Since I have `highline` installed already, I thought I'd try that solution... but when I do, I get: `NameError (Bad color or uninitialized constant SystemExtensions)` -- is there some other additional gem that needs to be installed?  Also, as has been mentioned, it's `tput cols`, not `tput columns`, and that works for me under ubuntu.  But a standard-library solution is better, so I'm going with the `io/console` answer that's also listed here.

Answer (score 48):

There is a common unix command:

```
tput cols
```

This returns the width of the terminal.

Answer (score 37):

```
def winsize
 #Ruby 1.9.3 added 'io/console' to the standard library.
 require 'io/console'
 IO.console.winsize
 rescue LoadError
 # This works with older Ruby, but only with systems
 # that have a tput(1) command, such as Unix clones.
[Integer(`tput li`), Integer(`tput co`)]
end

rows, cols = winsize
printf "%d rows by %d columns\n", rows, cols
```

[Link](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Terminal_control/Dimensions#Ruby)

Comment: Points for this being part of the standard library!  Gems are great and all, but for something so simple, it's nice not to need to install anything extra.

Answer (score 9):

If you want your code to work across platforms, here's what I use: http://github.com/cldwalker/hirb/blob/master/lib/hirb/util.rb#L61-71

Also check out the system_extensions file in [highline](http://highline.rubyforge.org/)

Comment: Thanks for giving me exactly what I wanted! BTW, Gabriel, I'm using your hirb gem in my rails console and I'm just loving it. thanks man.

Answer (score 7):

```
    require 'io/console'
    puts "Rows by columns: #{IO.console.winsize}"
    puts "Ruby 2.6.4"
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer, please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.

Comment: This is simple and comes with Ruby by default. It's a shame it's at the bottom.

Comment: There is also another shame here. *The provided comments are flagged as a Low Quality Comments. These provided comments may be correct, but they could benefit from being made with reading the answer before commenting it. Bot reply only comments are not considered "good" comments. There are other comments that provide the same copypasta, and they were posted thousands of times already. When posting a comment, please make sure you add a new or a substantially comment, especially when commenting the correct answer like this one.*

Answer (score 6):

Ruby actually comes with a built-in class called "Curses", which lets you do all kinds of things with the terminal window.

For example, you can do this:

```
require 'curses'

Curses.init_screen()

puts Curses.lines # Gives you the height of terminal window
puts Curses.cols # Gives you the width of terminal window
```

For more info: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses/Window.html

Comment: Update: As of ruby 2.1+, curses is no longer part of the standard library. It has now been moved into its own gem. See: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8584

Answer (score 5):

I'm a bit late but in rake tasks I do the following: Rake.application.terminal_width

Comment: Great answer, thanks so much! I needed it specifically inside a Rake task.

Answer (score 3):

ENV['COLUMNS'] will give you the number of columns in the terminal.

Comment: I tried it in IRB and inspected the ENV hash but couldn't find the columns key.

Comment: This trick must be specific to some shells or operating systems.  It didn't work under Bash on Debian, either.

Comment: That worked for me in Ubuntu 11.04. I need to modify it so my code isn't truncated, hopefully this helps. (GNOME Terminal 2.32.1)

Comment: In OSX and Solaris, it only works for bash, not for programs that run under bash. If you run env in bash you won't see it, but "echo $COLUMNS" works. In ruby on these platforms, ENV['COLUMNS'] is nil.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on macOS 10.14, no such environment variable is set, not even with Bash. However, `tput cols` works on macOS.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the [tty-screen](https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty-screen) gem to detect terminal size across different OS systems and Ruby interpreters. It covers many ways of checking the size including Win API on Windows, Java libs on JRuby and Unix utilities.

This is a module which you can include in your class or call directly:

```
require 'tty-screen'

TTY::Screen.size     # => [51, 280]
TTY::Screen.width    # => 280
TTY::Screen.height   # => 51
```

For more info see: https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty-screen