# Access environment variable in IRB but not when running file

Tags: ruby, environment-variables

```
require 'io/console'
def test
  IO.console.winsize
end

puts "1: test: #{test()}"
puts "2: env: #{ENV['COLUMNS']}"
```

When I run this, this is what I see in my console:

```
 1: test: [23, 80]
 2: env:
```

In other words, I'm not able to print out ENV['COLUMNS'] when I run the program

However, typing ENV['COLUMNS'] within IRB gives me a string equal to the terminal width.

I am wondering why this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only variables that are `exported` by your shell will be available in a Ruby script:

```
$ ruby -e "puts ENV['COLUMNS']"

$ export COLUMNS
$ ruby -e "puts ENV['COLUMNS']"
80
```

- [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956850/read-all-shell-variables-in-ruby#answer-12021550) presents a possible workaround (follow the first link and check out the `yaml` branch on Github)
- [here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068859/how-to-get-the-width-of-terminal-window-in-ruby#answer-10444128) that presents a way to get the terminal size without using shell variables